# Property 'createMediaStreamDestination' does not exist on type 'AudioContext'

Tags: audiocontext

I am getting above error while trying to get a stream from a File, via Audio Tag.

```
     this.audioElement = document.getElementById('audioSend');
     var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
     var source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(this.audioElement);
     var dst  = audioCtx.createMediaStreamDestination();
```

Answer (score 0):

createMediaStreamDestination() is supported in the following browsers:

Chrome since 10.0

Firefox since 25.0

Safari since 6.0

Opera since 15.0

But not IE nor Edge.

Source: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode

The lack of support of Edge is a bit odd since it is documented on their site:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn954877(v=vs.85).aspx

Which browser are you targeting?

Comment: I am testing on Chrome, and ionic platform

Comment: Then it should be supported. To verify, open Chrome's console then type this:
`code`console.log(new AudioContext().createMediaStreamDestination());
It should return:
`code`MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode {stream: MediaStream, context: AudioContext, numberOfInputs: 1, numberOfOutputs: 1, channelCount: 2, ...}

Comment: I have the same problem, my project not compile because the error with createMediaStreamDestination